# Comparing temperature of two similar bodies with varying specific heat capacity to $(Ta+Tb)/2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

(given below is a question from IAT 2021)

[image: IAT question 7 physics 2021]

Answer given to this question is D.
I am a bit confused as to how this problem needs to be solved and am unable to resolve further. Kindly correct where am I going wrong.

My attempt:

assuming co-relation between Temperature and specific heat capacity as directly proportion(due to ambiguity in given question),

$$C=kT$$

so, $$\int_{T_f}^{T_a}{kT}dT=\int_{T_b}^{T_f}{kT}dT$$
thus,
$$(T_a^2-T_f^2)=(T_f^2-T_b^2)$$
so ,
$$T_f=\sqrt{\frac{T_a^2+T_b^2}{2}}$$

assuming my steps must have been wrong due to inability to solve further.
*Do not hesitate to say question is wrong or a wrong option is given (in case) as this is **not the final answer key** from the exam but the key to be challenged.*

Comment: Your answer seems to be within the interval $T>(T_a + T_b)/2$. So with your specific linear model you obtain an  answer compatible with the one reported as correct.

Comment: thank you! pardon my foolishness :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity under your square root sign can be expressed as:
$$\frac{T_a^2+T_b^2}{2}=\left(\frac{T_a+T_b}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{T_a-T_b}{2}\right)^2$$This is clearly greater than $\left(\frac{T_a+T_b}{2}\right)^2$.